# Uploading file by User Id in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables one is for users and one is for images 
All what I would like to achieve is that if I  log in I can be able to upload images for a user 
Since no user will be allowed  to upload images I wanna upload images for them and each and every user will be able to view his own images . I have a working code to upload  multiple images but now
How to assign them to a specific user .
the code bellow just uploads multiple images .

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
$username = (isset ($_POST['username']));
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $query = "INSERT into tish_images(`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`)
             VALUES(:FILE_NAME,:FILE_SIZE,:FILE_TYPE)";
    $stmt  = $con->prepare($query);
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error ){
        if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $errors[] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
            continue;
        }
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
            continue;
        }
        try{       
            $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_NAME', $file_name , PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_SIZE', $file_size, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_TYPE', $file_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();

            $desired_dir="image_uploads";

            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);// Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_file($desired_dir.'/'.$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name);
            }else{    //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_file=$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name.time();
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$new_file) ;               
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $errors[] = $file_name . 'not saved in db.';
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }   
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: well, err.. make a image2user table storing this information? ( if an image can only belong to one user, this could be done in the images table itself, not that I recommend that)

Comment: @Najzero its like I am the user table will contain the user infor and the id which will identify this user in the images table but also I wanna knw. can these images be stored in one box ? just like 1,2,3,5 not each emage to get its own coloumn

Comment: Each image is a different row. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can do one thing . Create a column for the user_id in the images table and when you insert the images insert the respective user_id accordingly. So in the front end either you can have a drop-down of all the users or if you are using session to store user id then you can get that easily.

Do let me know if you need any thing else.

Comment: I will be back to you what you are sayig sounds to be great let me try it

Answer (score 1):

You have separate table for user and images or one table?

Comment: I have two but I can even use 1 if it easier

Comment: you will use two table one for user and second for images and user_id will be foreign key in images table

Answer (score 1):

you need a table like `users_uploads` which contains these fields: `user_id` and `file_name`. After that you will have data like the following:

```
user_id : file_name
1 : abc.jpg
2 : 123.png
1 : xyz.bmp
1 : blah.mp3
3 : blah.mp3
```

if you want to store all uploads in one column like `abc.jpg;xyz.bmp;blah.mp3` it's possible, but it's slower than the previous way because you need to process the strings which are stored in that column. Imagine you want to delete a file `xyz.bmp`, you need extract all the files, remove that particular entry from the array and then write them back to that cell. That takes much longer rather deleting or selecting a row from database ... seriously.

Comment: ok @Mahdi great I understand so u mean I should install em in a different column and each column should contain a referencing user Id?

Comment: @humphrey yes, each `file_name` should point out to its `user_id` (owner)